# iTerm2 - Disable same commands across tabs

Tags: terminal, macos, iterm

Terminal app in Sierra keeps crashing so I switched to iTerm. But iTerm tabs behave weirdly. Whatever I do in one tab automatically replicates across all open tabs! Am I missing some setting to turn this off? Please help.

Attached a gif showing that I open 1 file in tab 3, upon switching to tabs 1, 2 I see the same file open.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watching your tab titles in the GIF, it looks like you're using `Move Tab Left`, which is moving the tab you opened `vim` in to the left.

What you need is `Select Previous Tab` to change tabs, or even `CMD-1` to move to tab1, etc.

Answer (score 7):

In the Menu: Shell > Broadcast Input > Send Input to Current Session Only

Comment: this setting is what is selected. please see my screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lVp4.jpg. In Spite of this setting being "send input to current session only" I see this behavior. Please advise.

Comment: Whai if you select Send to all sessions and then rollback to Current Session Only?

Comment: This did not work for me.